# Static library compiled for x86 macos looks like an iPhone simulator library

Tags: xcode, go, cgo, xcframework

I have a Cgo library that I'm trying to build for Darwin. My ultimate goal is to have an xcframework that contains versions of the library for macos and iOS, both in x86 and arm64 versions.

My invocation to build the Cgo library looks like this:

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 \
GOOS=darwin \
GOARCH=amd64 \
SDK=macosx \
CC=$(ROOT_DIR)clangwrap.sh \
go build -buildmode=c-archive -tags ios -o $(MACOS_OUT)/x86_64/mylib.a .
```

`clangwrap.sh` is a simple script to invoke clang based on the SDK:

```
SDK_PATH=`xcrun --sdk $SDK --show-sdk-path`
CLANG=`xcrun --sdk $SDK --find clang`

if [ "$GOARCH" == "amd64" ]; then
    CARCH="x86_64"
elif [ "$GOARCH" == "arm64" ]; then
    CARCH="arm64"
fi

MIN_VERSION=""
if [ "$SDK" == "macosx" ]; then
    MIN_VERSION="-mmacosx-version-min=10.15"
elif [ "$SDK" == "iphoneos" ] || [ "$SDK" == "iphonesimulator" ]; then
    MIN_VERSION="-mios-version-min=10.0"
fi

exec $CLANG -arch $CARCH -isysroot $SDK_PATH $MIN_VERSION "$@"
```

The issue I'm having is that `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` complains that there is a duplicate library for x86-ios-simulator. If I look at the macos binary with `otool`, I see that it seems to be an ios binary:

```
> otool -l lib/darwin/macos/x86_64/mylib.a
Load command 1
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.0
      sdk 15.2
Load command 2
     cmd LC_SYMTAB
 cmdsize 24
  symoff 6312
   nsyms 9
  stroff 6456
 strsize 184
```

Any idea on how to produce a proper macos binary?